# Execute task every second and another task when done

Tags: android, timer, timertask

So i want to have a timer wich executes a some methods when it is done counting to 3. But i would like to have it display a toast every second like a countdown.

I now have:

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        doSomething()
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 3 * 1000);
```

This executes doSomething() after 3 seconds. So how can i add a method to be performed every second?

So that it does:

0sec: Toast saying 3

1sec: Toast saying 2

2sec: Toast saying 1

3sec: executing doSomething()

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
private static final int SHORT_DELAY = 1000; //1 sec

   new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() { 
      int i=1; 
        @Override 
        public void run() { 
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() { 
                   //Can u check logs if running?
                   Log.d("Timer running",String.valueOf(i));
                    i++;
                    if(i%4==0) //started with 1 so -->2,3,4
                      doSomething() 
                    else
                      Toast.maketext(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(i-1),
                      SHORT_DELAY).show();
                } 
            }); 
        } 
    },0,  1000);
```

Do cancel it at appropriate place. maybe when your work is done, or immediately when doSomething() is called.

Comment: With your edited version, it shows a "2" in a Toast, and then does nothing else. Wich is the 1 with the ++ wich then becomes 2. and it only executes once

Comment: fixed to i-1, can you share where you cancel the timer?

Comment: i never cancel the timer i have in my question. After 3 seconds, it executes the doSomething method and the code goes on from there.

Comment: when doSomething() is called first time you should cancel the timer since it will keep running lik 1-->2-->3-->doSomething. what is puzzling me though is why your task doesn't go beyond 1

Comment: it is just not iterating i think. it only runs trough it once, wich returns the "2"

Comment: with the edited version the log says 4, 8, 12 and then crashes with error: